# Android game local multiplayer implementation

Tags: java, android, multiplayer

I made a simple 2d game in Android Studio (player shooting, chests, enemy spawning and so on..) as a school project. I've done some research in different multiplayer options, but i can't really decide for which to go for, since i want a clean, fast and not overcomplicated solution. I suppose it would be easier to implement local multiplayer with wifi direct or bluetooth with one device beign a host. Any help would be really appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ,I have some website you can visit to get an idea on how to create your multiplayer game,

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nj-trslVFPc (It shows how to create a multiplayer game with firebase)
2. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136583/can-i-make-a-multiplayer-android-game-using-android-studio (It has list of modules and libraries you can use to create your game)
3. I would have suggest you to use `Real-time Multiplayer` Support provided by Android but it is depreciated now. But you can take a look at it https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer